# Is it reasonable to expect a home sewer system to handle 2-ply toilet paper?

Tags: plumbing, sewer

I own a fixer-upper that has... more problems than I originally anticipated. The current problem that I'm working on tackling is that the sewer line under the basement blocks if 2-ply toilet paper is regularly used. It doesn't matter which brand is used - even brands that are known for disintegrating very quickly - any brand of 2-ply blocks the sewer line. 1-ply seems to be okay so far. Also, nothing abnormal is going down the drain - no oils/fats (beyond just, like, doing the dishes), no hair, no dental floss, no wet-wipes, nothing.

But, this isn't like some ancient rural house or anything special like that; this is your average American suburban house connected to the city sewer. It's completely reasonable to expect the sewer line to *not* block from just 2-ply paper, right? Like, this is not an unreasonble expectation of me to have for a plumbing system, is it?

Comment: If 2-ply is causing blockages, then I'm sure you have trouble with any sort of firm material (I'd think a #2 being flushed would cause more problems than just TP).  What's the age of the house, and where are you located?  It's likely you have a partial blockage.  This could be roots, collapsed, pipe, Orangeburg sewer line, or some other blockage.  Best suggestion is to get a plumber with inspection camera and see what's really going on.

Comment: It's not the ply, if you used twice as much single ply, that would be the same amount of paper.  In the meantime, flush often.  More water will keep things moving and it's cheaper than a plumber.  But you do need to get it fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like the system suffers from damage, poor workmanship, or (possibly) a persistent blockage that isn't getting fully cleared when you've dealt with the 2-ply blockage in the past.

You're probably going to need to call in an experience plumber, but there are things you could do in advance to prepare:

1. Contact your sewer operator. That might be the city, or a sewer district serving several cities. Ask for whatever information they may have about your sewer lateral, including the location of any cleanout that may be in the yard.
2. If there is a cleanout in the yard, consider digging a little bit to find it. One would hope that its cap is buried shallow, and that the sewer operator has good measurements to help you find it..
3. Identify the location of cleanouts in the house; also try to figure out whether your house has a backwater valve (a backflow prevention device for sewers). Make sure all these things are accessible.

Start calling plumbers. Ask questions that might help you figure out who is well-equipped to help with your problem. For example:

- Can they run a camera down the drain lines? In which sizes of pipe (2, 3, or 4 inch)? Does the camera enter through a cleanout, a floor drain, a toilet flange, etc? How far can they push it before it has to be removed and try again at a new point?
- Is the camera picture good enough to identify burrs or other problems at pipe edges? Roots or other impingement on/into the pipe? Whether there's a "belly" in the pipe where water and solids pool?
- Do they use a sonde (aka beacon) and a locator to be able to mark exactly where to dig to access a trouble spot?

Comment: Called a plumber. He did the cameras, and removed some blockage that the previous plumber had  missed. Here's hoping it's fixed for good now. 